# YouTube stream with DRM key rotation can only play 2 min

Tags: cobalt

The tricky point is, with the same cobalt and porting code, we could play them about one month ago.
Then in near term, we find the stream can not play well. From log, no key rotation happens. 
But our software has no change.
Anything updated on YouTube server side?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to provide more information on this? i.e. the platform, the version of Cobalt, etc..